# What is the downside of scanning with regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I know that in addition to scanning for predefined `primitive` types, I can also scan for my own user-defined patterns, which is helpful when scanning more complex data. I'm talking about the `Scanner.next(String pattern)` method.
However, in the book I read about Java, there's a paragraph that says

> "There’s one caveat when scanning with regular expressions. The
>   pattern is matched against the next input token only, so if your
>   pattern contains a delimiter it will never be matched."

I don't really understand what this means and in which situations this type of scanning is not applicable

Comment: What book are you referring to? SO isn't a validation site for arbitrary uncited junk.

Comment: Thinking in Java, 4th edition - Bruce Eckel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a comma `,` as a delimiter. Now somehow (maybe it was provided by someone else) you've come up with a pattern `ab,cd`. Since the pattern contains the delimiter, the scanner will attempt to match `ab,cd` first to `ab` and then to `cd`, resulting in no match.

Note that this is a *caveat*, and it's not necessarily something that you'd easily encounter.

Comment: Can you explain how the delimiter and pattern in your example are used? I thought the **pattern will be used as the delimiter by scanner**. How can that be 2 different things?

Comment: @Codebender Just like `nextInt()` will scan for an integer (with `\n` as a delimiter and whatever else the default delimiters are), the `next(String pattern)` would scan for next input that matches the pattern. The input is first tokenized according to the delimiters, after that the matching is done whether it's a regex pattern, an integer, line etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just noticed the `next(pattern)` methods exist. I was thinking about using the pattern as the delimiter using `useDelimiter(pattern)`.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the original example given in the book "Thinking in Java", this program:

```
String threatData =
        "58.27.82.161@02/10/2005\n" +
        "204.45.234.40@02/11/2005\n" +
        "58.27.82.161@02/11/2005\n" +
        "58.27.82.161@02/12/2005\n" +
        "58.27.82.161@02/12/2005\n" +
        "[Next log section with different data format]";

Scanner sc = new Scanner(threatData);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+([.]\\d+){3})@" + "(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})");
                                             ///     ^
while(sc.hasNext(pattern)) {
    System.out.println(sc.next(pattern));  
    MatchResult matchResult = sc.match();
    System.out.println("Threat from " + matchResult.group(1) + " on " + matchResult.group(3));
}
```

correctly prints the desired output. **But,** when you make slight alteration to it by replacing `@` in *threatData* with whitespace `' '` and `@` in *pattern* with `\\s`,  you will observe that the scanner **fails to match** the pattern as it contains a default delimiter.

```
String threatData =
        "58.27.82.161 02/10/2005\n" +
        "204.45.234.40 02/11/2005\n" +
        "58.27.82.161 02/11/2005\n" +
        "58.27.82.161 02/12/2005\n" +
        "58.27.82.161 02/12/2005\n" +
        "[Next log section with different data format]";

Scanner sc = new Scanner(threatData);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+([.]\\d+){3})\\s" + "(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})");
                                                //    ^^
```